# How to optimize the IF condition with many conditions and same output

Tags: php, javascript

My intention is to write sustainable and easy to read code. Also matter on performance because this should be at core of app so it will be pass through hundreds of times.
Do you have any advice to optimase this long code?
My first thought was to write it as array and check if array contains.

```
      if(string == "apple"){
        Detail = false;
        bShowNew = true;        
      }
      if(string == "banana"){
        Detail = false;
        bShowNew = true;       
      }
      if(string == "kiwi"){
        Detail = false;
        bShowNew = true;          
      }
      if(string == "lemon"){
        Detail = false;
        bShowNew = true;          
      }
      if(string == "lime"){
        Detail = false;
        bShowNew = true;          
      }
      if(string == "mango"){
        Detail = false;
        bShowNew = true;         
      }
      if(string == "orange"){
        Detail = false;
        bShowNew = true;        
      }
      if(string == "pear"){
        Detail = false;
        bShowNew = true;           
      }
      if(string == "pineapple"){
        Detail = false;
        bShowNew = true;            
      }
      if(string == "plum"){
        Detail = false;
        bShowNew = true;          
      }
      if(string == "greenapple"){
        Detail = false;
        bShowNew = true;    
      }
      if(string == "redapple"){
        Detail = false;
        bShowNew = true;          
      }
      if(string == "blueapple"){
        Detail = false;
        bShowNew = true;        
      }
      if(string == "grenkiwi"){
        Detail = false;
        bShowNew = true;           
      }
      if(string == "brownkiwi"){
        Detail = false;
        bShowNew = true;           
      }
      if(string == "yellowmango"){
        Detail = false;
        bShowNew = true;         
      }
      if(string == "redmango"){
        Detail = false;
        bShowNew = true;           
      }
      if(string == "greenmango"){
        Detail = false;
        bShowNew = true;           
      }
      if(string == "purpleplum"){
        Detail = false;
        bShowNew = true;           
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Sure

You could use `in_array` for this type of check, something like this

```php
if (in_array($string, ['apple', 'banana', 'kiwi'])) { // keep adding as many as you need
    $Detail = false;
    $bShowNew = true;
}
```

If your array gets to big you can create a variable that will contain that array

```php
$allowed = [
    'apple',
    'banana',
    'kiwi'
    // etc... 
];

if (in_array($string, $allowed)) { // keep adding as many as you need
    $Detail = false;
    $bShowNew = true;
}
```

This will do exactly the same but is a bit cleaner and easier to read